# How to assign /home partition of LinuxMint when I replace LinuxMint with Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, home-directory

I have recently bought a HP laptop and installed 64-bit LinuxMint 17.3 XFCE edition. The partitioning that I have done is 50GB for root, 8GB for swap and the remaining disk space ~407GB as /home. Now, I want to remove LinuxMint and install 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04 when it arrives.
I do not wish to partition my hdd again and I have quite a lot of data in my /home partition.
Can I install Ubuntu 16.04 on the root partition and will it automatically use the /home partition as its home? Or, would I need to do some extra configuration to assign this /home partition to Ubuntu?
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

By default Ubuntu will create a dual boot with the existing Mint, or it will wipe and overwrite all of your hard drive(s), depending on your choice.

To install Ubuntu on the existing Mint partition with keeping HOME on the other partition you need to choose "Do someting else" on installation.

This will open the graphical partition manager Gparted for a custom partitioning of your drive(s). You may not need to create new partitions but you should take care on where the mount points are.

- Take care to tick **format** for the root partition at mount point `/` (where Mint resides) only.
- **Do not tick format** for your previous home partition. Choose this partition to have its mount point `/home`.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I install Ubuntu 16.04 on the root partition and will it automatically use the /home partition as its home?

The easiest method is to tell it to do so yourself.

> Or, would I need to do some extra configuration to assign this /home partition to Ubuntu?

Pick "something else" and mount the partitions Mint is installed on as /home *without formatting it*. You can also set / and swap from the partitions you already have but do format those. A separate data partitions you have (ntfs or ext) can be mounted the same way; that one also *without formatting it*.